# Cannot assign variable in for-loop in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, directory-listing

I tried to assign variable `a` in for-loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in `ls`
do
  a = $file
done
```

But when I run, it gave error:

```
line 5: a: command not found
```

Why did it give error? How to assign variable `a`?

Comment: Prefer `$()` over backticks and generally avoid parsing output of `ls`. Learn to use globbing a.k.a. filename expansion.

Comment: @reinardhz : This is not an assignment, but an invocation of the command  named `a`, with `=` as first argument.  Similarily, `touch =` would create a file named `=` and not create a variable named `touch`.

Comment: @user1934428 Yeah I shouldn't put spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be no spaces on both sides of the equal sign when defining variables in the Shell.

It should be:

```
a=$file
```

Answer (score 1):

You need remove spaces i.e.

```
a = $file
```

must be

```
a=$file
```